# ToggleButton prevents my app from starting

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, crash, togglebutton

I am making a calculator for a minigame, everything worked fine until I added a toggleButton. The app crashes on start, but I could not find any errors.

JAVA code:

```
.
.
.    
    int colorOff = getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOff);
    int colorOn = getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOn);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_balot_calculator); }

//This method is supposed to change the color of the toggle button when it is checked and not checked.
    public void seraA(View view) {
        ToggleButton seraToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.sera_toggle);
            if (seraToggle.isChecked()) {
                seraToggle.setBackgroundColor(colorOn); }
            else
                seraToggle.setBackgroundColor(colorOff);
    }
.
.
.
```

XML code:

```
.
.
.
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/sera_toggle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
    android:onClick="seraA"
    android:textOn="@string/sera_T"
    android:textOff="@string/sera_T"
    android:textColor="#E0F7FA"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
.
.
.
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.detailedbalotcalculator/com.example.android.detailedbalotcalculator.BalotCalculator}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: Are there any references that are directly referencing your code? This way it's almost impossible to help you

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just new to coding, what would clarify my problem to you? There are no direct errors referring to the code and I am not allowed to paste the logcat in the question because it is more code than words.

Comment: You can use Gist from github and then put the link here: https://gist.github.com/ or without account use https://www.pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks, here is a link to the Gist: https://gist.github.com/AmmarShafi98/9a107740a32cb93bebc88d35ac1d8586

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the following line gives it away:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

I assume your class isn't initialized when making the getResources() call

Try this instead:

```
int colorOff;
int colorOn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mini_game); 
    colorOff = getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOff);
    colorOn = getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOn);
}
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. The app keeps crashing on start and the logcat shows the same errors.

Comment: Try commenting out the parts with getResources and see if it works. That way we can be sure, the error is caused by this and can then further investigate

Comment: I just researched a little bit more, apparently you now call int colorOff = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.my_view_color);

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by deleting the variables `colorOn` and `colorOff`. It looks almost the same but it works this way.

```
    //int colorOff = getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOff);
    //int colorOn = getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOn);

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mini_game);
        }

//This method is supposed to change the color of the toggle button when it is checked and not checked.

    public void seraA(View view) {
        ToggleButton seraToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.sera_toggle);
        if (seraToggle.isChecked()) {
            seraToggle.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOn));
        } else
            seraToggle.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toggleOff));
    }
```